# Send Console Window output to discord Channel

Tags: c#, console, discord, discord.net

I am working on a function to send console window output to a [discord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Discord) channel.

i managed to make it work but i can't get the main goal of the function.

i want to get the output directly from the console instead of getting the output from the logger class which i have.

i have a separate logger class which controls all logging, that would be standard way but i have never tried to get the output directly from console.

i have searched and found Console.Out() method but i guess its mainly used for writing to text file.

i am using [Discord.Net](https://github.com/RogueException/Discord.Net).

here is the sample function which i call from the logger class.

```
public sealed class LogToChannel : DiscordHandler
{
    public static async Task SendToChannel(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!IsServerOnline || string.IsNullOrEmpty(message) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message))
            {
                return;
            }

            string shortDate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
            string shortTime = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();                
            string LogFormat = $"[{shortDate} {shortTime}] {message}";
            await Task.Delay(200).ConfigureAwait(false);
            await Client.GetGuild(4646556464646464546).GetTextChannel(546464654646546465).SendMessageAsync(LogFormat).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if(ex is NullReferenceException)
            {
                throw;                   
            }
            else
            {
                SGF.SGFLogger.LogException(ex);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Edits! I was in a hurry so couldn't Format it correctly.

Comment: .is this using .net core at all?

Comment: yes it is on .net core

Comment: ok, If you are on .NET Core, it does not matter whether you use `ConfigureAwait(false)` or not because Core does not have a `SynchronizationContext`.  ref: http://hamidmosalla.com/2018/06/24/what-is-synchronizationcontext/

Comment: Ok i will Look to it! thanks